# URl Redirect issue in Magento as a result of Import/Export Attribute bug

Tags: magento, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I am fairly new to the Magento store and I encountered an issue. I was working on some price updates and uploaded a few products via the import function. The system then proceeded to delete a whole bunch of attributes in addition to removing image settings and URL paths. I have figured out how to replace the missing attributes (Bulk Update via the catalog) and the images (manual radio button selection under item settings), but I have been unable to fix the url issue.

The correct URL path looks like this:

pmlit-g2-0-bmw-1-series-e82-e88-1m-led-6w-h8-energize-blue-angel-eyes-bulbs-kit.html

But the URL path in the system after the bug is:
 --379.html

the --379.html url gives a 404 error.

I have reindexed the Catalog URL rewrites and flushed the magento cache and cache storage.

IF I go into the Catalog > URL Rewrite Management, I cannot actually edit the target URL.

Any advice on this would be great. Thanks.